# Site links broken after Permalink change (404)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, permalinks, polylang

I just changed my permalink structure from

https://www.maleq.org/en/first-coming-british-royal-family/

to

https://www.maleq.org/first-coming-british-royal-family/

Removing the /en/ sub in the url. Now though all of my l=previous posted links on social media are broken and all of my google traffic does not get directed correctly. Therefore all links with the /en/ get a 404 page error.

I have tried to modify the .htaccess folder but I am not having much luck.

Any help is super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Replace with below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: This is the source for my answer: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

Comment: Hey Thanks so much!  

I added it into my .htaccess file as follows.



`# BEGIN WordPress


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

So far though I am still having no luck.  I tried clearing my caches and waiting a bit too, but no luck yet.

Comment: I updated my answer, are you able to format your the exact way it shows in your htaccess file? You are definitely in the right htaccess file and there isn't a duplicate? You could try have just that one line in there as a rewrite rule instead of the others and see what happens. If all else fails, use a plug in like this. They are great to have anyway :) https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the help.

Sadly after many tries I never hot the .htaccess file to work, but i did find a solution!

I used the "Simple 301 Redirects" plug-in.

I used /en/* is the example, then my url with an * like this https://www.MaleQ.org/*/ in the second box and chose "wildcards".

This seems to have fixed the problem.

Thank you so much for the help!